# Find a function with the following properties

Tags: limits, functions

Find a function $f(x)$ so that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=\infty$

I have plugged maybe a hundred functions but I can't seem to figure this out. I'm wondering whether such a function exists at all since we need to find some function that goes to zero extremely slow.

Could somebody help me out?

Comment: which functions did you try? The answer is not that complicated. If you tried hundred functions I am sure you tried the answer.

Comment: are you sure there is no typo in the second limit ? Otherwise any positive function that goes to 0 at infinity will do

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac1x$. It is not hard to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1x = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{\frac1{f(x)}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} x^x = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try $f(x) = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$? This function works, but is defined only for $x>0$ so I don't know if that is sufficient. Moreover, I am not sure because of the typo in the second limit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Since the first condition ($f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$) is simpler, try to think of relatively simple functions that satisfy it.  Then see if the function(s) you come up with also satisfy the second condition.  If not, keep trying.

Second hint:  I disagree that such an $f(x)$ will need to approach $0$ slowly.  This is based on the answer I came up with, and it approaches $0$ pretty rapidly as $x \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(x)=e^{-x}$, which also debunks your intuition.

Comment: Same one I thought of.

Comment: ha +1 for being first